# How to control SensorExposureTime and SensorSensitivity(ISO) manually in camera2 android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-camera, android-camera2

Below is the code snippet to set the SensorExposureTime and SensorSensitivity(ISO) values manually,

```
builder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAeMode, new Java.Lang.Integer((int)ControlAEMode.Off));
builder.Set(CaptureRequest.SensorExposureTime, Long.ValueOf("1000000"));   // nano secs 1/250=4E6
builder.Set(CaptureRequest.SensorSensitivity, 2000);
```

With manual control of auto exposure the camera preview is displayed with black distortion lines.

[image]

If I change ControlAeMode to "on" then the camera preview is displayed properly.

[image]

I am testing this with Moto x4 device which has level_3 hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing flickering of your office lighting.  Normally, autoexposure compensates for the power line flicker of your fluorescent lights, but when you switch to manual exposure this isn't possible.

Try testing outdoors or under other illumination to verify.

Comment: We tested in outdoor, we still found the black distortion lines.

Comment: That suggests a strange bug in the camera implementation, unfortunately. I don't have any suggestions on how to avoid it.